# Expected argument of type "App\Entity\CategoryImage", "array" given at property path "images"

Tags: forms, image, symfony, upload

I try to insert images with relations OneToMany, but I get an error.

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\CategoryImage", "array" given at  property path "images".

I have  entities  Category and CategoryImage:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
    class Category 
{
  /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CategoryImage", mappedBy="category", orphanRemoval=true ,cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $images;

   .......
}



/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryImageRepository")
 */
class CategoryImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;


    /** @var \SplFileInfo */
    protected $file;
....
}
```

Two forms:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $data = $builder->getForm()->getData();      
        $builder
            ->add('name')     
            ->add('parent',OptionType::class,[               
                'class'=>Category::class,  
                'selectType'=>'flatexcept',
                'required'=>false,
            ])
        ->add('images',CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type' => ImageTypeMultiple::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            ]);

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Category::class,
    ]);
}
}

class ImageTypeMultiple extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder->add('file',FileType::class,[
            'label'=>false,  
            'required'=>false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Image([
                       'maxSize' => '5M'
                ])
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'image_multiple';
    }   
}
```

My custom ImageTypeMultiple form_theme widget:

```
{% block image_multiple_widget -%}
    {% spaceless %}  
        {% if form.vars.value.path|default(null) is null %}
            <label for="{{ form.file.vars.id }}" class="image-upload btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class="fa-cloud fa icon"></i> {{ 'select'|trans }}</label>
        {% else %}
            <img src="{{ form.vars.value.path|imagine_filter('sylius_small') }}" />
            <label for="{{ form.file.vars.id }}" class="image-upload btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class="fa-cloud fa icon"></i> {{ 'replace'|trans }}</label>
        {% endif %}       
         <div class="d-none">
            {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
        </div>       
        <div class="element">
            {{- form_errors(form.file) -}}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}



{% block collection_widget -%}
    {% import _self as self %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default ~ ' controls collection-widget'}) %}

    {% spaceless %}
        <div data-form-type="collection" {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}
                {% if prototype is defined and allow_add %}
                    data-prototype='{{ self.collection_item(prototype, allow_delete, 'Delete', '__name__')|e }}'
                {%- endif -%}
        >
            {{ form_errors(form) }}

            {% if prototypes|default is iterable %}
                {% for key, subPrototype in prototypes %}
                    <input type="hidden" data-form-prototype="{{ key }}" value="{{ self.collection_item(subPrototype, allow_delete, button_delete_label, '__name__')|e }}" />
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            <div data-form-collection="list" class="row">
                {% for child in form %}
                    {{ self.collection_item(child, allow_delete, 'Delete', loop.index0) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            {% if prototype is defined and allow_add %}
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-form-collection="add">                   
                    Add
                </a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock collection_widget %}

{% macro collection_item(form, allow_delete, button_delete_label, index) %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div data-form-collection="item" data-form-collection-index="{{ index }}" class='col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 imagetype_widget ml-3 mb-3' >
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                {% if allow_delete %}
                 <a href="#" data-form-collection="delete" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash "></i>
                   Delete
                </a>
            {% endif %}           
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

My controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="category_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Category $category): Response
    {     

        $form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category);      

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {   
...}
```

}

I can open my edit page without error:

[image]

but after I select an image under **images** field and submit, it shows this error:

[image]

It shows

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\CategoryImage", "array" given at property path "images".

on the line  `$form->handleRequest($request)` in the controller ,something goes wrong, I have been dealing with this problem for days, but cannot solve it.

Comment: Can you please add all of the code for your controller and the others because it makes it hard to help with the limited information available

Comment: OK,you can clone my full project with git@github.com:bruceleedrupal/hierarchical.git, after clone you run this commands : composer update  && yarn encore dev --watch ,after config database parameters in .env, run  bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force ,then pulish this site with nginx

Comment: After seting up go to page /category/new，click add under images,select a local image,fill the other fields and submit,you can see the error message

Comment: All my souce code lives under src directory

Comment: Can you please do a data dump of the`$request` variable and post it here?

Comment: [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7478954/67740605-582ab680-fa51-11e9-9762-b7af5a969f48.png) open the link to see my request dump